# AngularJs: The expression of the orderBy doesnt work to me

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, sql-order-by

I'm using AngularJs 1.2.8. Here's my question:

I want to order an array of objects using a filter, and a strange thing happens to me.

When I use the `ng-repeat="thread in threads"` without any filter it orders it by ascendant.

When I use the `ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-':true"` it orders it by descendant.

Here's the problem: when I use `ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-':false"` it orders it by descendant anyway.

Thank you all.

Comment: Post your data - how does threads object look like?

Comment: The thread is an object that has ints, strings, booleans, even and array of comments inside. Things like Title, Id, date, etc

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to order your list based on a certain property? Usually orderBy is used in relation to a property within each item in ng-repeat:

**Descending** based on an example property title

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-title'"`

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-date'"`

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-id'"`

**Ascending** based on an example property title

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '-title'"`

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '+date'"`

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: '+id'"`

Angular documentation on [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). Notice the '+' or '-' are affixed to beginning of property name within the single quote characters.

You can also use in combination with a custom filter named query, perhaps on a text input element with ng-model="query". For example:

`ng-repeat="thread in threads | filter:query | orderBy: '-title'"`

Let me know if that helps or clarify question to identify properties of `thread` entity and what property you are hoping to sort on.

to order on index:

**Descending**
`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: thread.$index:true"`

**Ascending**
`ng-repeat="thread in threads | orderBy: thread.$index:false"`

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g9posLyp/

Comment: Yes, I tried mine because I read it somewhere and surprised me the fact that the false didn't affect it.

About your qüestion I like the idea but I dont have any Id to order by, shouldn't I be able to order it by the index of the array?

Comment: In your comment you stated something to the extent of "Things like Title, Id, date". Those are likely properties on your thread object such as thread.title, thread.id, thread.date or similar property names. Angular would need direction on which one of those properties to sort on. You're trying to sort on the index of the array? Would you be able to provide a use case for sorting on index?

Comment: if the index is Thread[0].Title, Thread[1].Title, Thread[2].Title, etc. I would like to order it by the index of the array of threads. I don't know if I answered ur question.

Comment: Yes, in fact is like a struct of Json data.

Comment: You could use an additional ng-repeat to iterate through each item in each thread then orderBy by id for example. Can you show sample of your incoming data?

Comment: See if `thread.$index:true` and/or `thread.index$:false` works for you

Comment: Did the answer updates and jsfiddle example help clarify the solution?

Comment: Please mark as best answer by clicking check mark icon near top of answer if it provided you a solution. Let me know if I can provide any additional help. Thanks!